# Load animations easily

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm programming an app that has several UIImage animations in different views. Now i'm using this line of code to load all the images:

```
[UIImage    imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"10001.png" ofType:nil]],
[UIImage    imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"10002.png" ofType:nil]],
[UIImage    imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"10003.png" ofType:nil]],
[UIImage    imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"10004.png" ofType:nil]],
[UIImage    imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"10005.png" ofType:nil]],
```

and load all the 100 images like this.

And then, on the second view, I load it like these:

```
[UIImage    imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"20001.png" ofType:nil]],
[UIImage    imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"20002.png" ofType:nil]],
[UIImage    imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"20003.png" ofType:nil]],
[UIImage    imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"20004.png" ofType:nil]],
[UIImage    imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"20005.png" ofType:nil]],
```

and again load the 100 images.

Is there any way to load all the images but only putting the name of the image one time? What I would like is to, for example, put the first 2 numbers (10) and then load the rest of the images automatically. Is it possible in Xcode? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (untested, but the idea should be clear)

```
- (NSArray *)loadImagesWithNumber:(NSInteger)number count:(NSUInteger)count
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];

    for(NSUInteger i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u.png", number + i];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];

        [array addObject:image];
    }

    return array;
}
```

Example: `NSArray *images = [self loadImagesWithNumber:1000 count:100];`, this would load 100 images starting with `1000.png` to `1099.png`.

Keep in mind that this doesn't work if you have images like `0000.png` to `0099.png` because the code doesn't add any leading zeroes. But that's trivial to add if you need it (feel free to ask if you need help with it)

Comment: stringWithFormat:%@"%u.png" --> stringWithFormat:@"%u.png" no? :)